# Unable to import Imagick package

Tags: go, imagick

I am trying to install the Imagick package for Go. I run the command:

```
go get gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick
```

As per [the documentation](https://gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick) but I always get this error:

```
# gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick
src/gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick/affine_matrix.go:8:35: fatal error: MagickWand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've looked online but have yet to find a solution that works. I have tried using `apt-get libmagickwand-dev` and that did not resolve the issue. I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Also* as per the documentation, `imagick.v3` supports ImageMagick version 7 and up. You have ImageMagick version 6.7.7-10. This is too old for imagick v3, and also too old for imagick v2, but v1 may work.

Comment: OT but I am curious about how did you manage to figure out what version OP is using?

Comment: @leafbebop I just looked up the version in Ubuntu 14.04 on packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: That's a lesson I missed. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Can apt-get be used to get 7 and up?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Mac OS High Sierra. First, you need to install ImageMagick and then specify the library path.

1. Install ImageMagick: (I used Homebrew)

   ```
   brew install imagemagick
   ```
2. Set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable if ImageMagick is not in your default system path:

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
   ```

   from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)
3. Go get the package:

   ```
   go get -u gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v3/imagick
   ```

To find out more about `pkg-config`, just type `man pkg-config`